# Exclude `[key: string]: string;` from extended interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Here's my problem:

I want to get keys of an interface by doing `keyof Type1`, the problem is that the `Type1` is extended by `Type2` and that one contains `[key: string]: SetOfValueTypes;` inside, so `keyof Type1` is useless without re-defining the type again. I still want to retain `SetOfValueTypes` check. So I want to keep the current definition of `Type1` but need only the key types of `Type1` without `Type2`.

The whole thing looks somewhat like this (this doesn't match my interfaces, just a simplified representation):

```
// Initial base type
interface Type2 {
  [key: string]: SetOfValueTypes;
}

// New type that extends Type2 to make sure values are one of possible types
interface Type1 extends Type2 {
  email: string;
  phone: number;
}

// Extracting keys from Type1
type KeysOfType1 = keyof Type1;

// The key can be any string, because of [key: string] definition in Type2
const someKey: KeysOfType1 = 'can be anything';
```

I would guess that it's impossible since `'email'` and `'phone'` literal types are a subset of `string` type, but I really hope there's a way without re-defining the `Type1` because `Type1` is quite big in my situation.

Comment: What is `SetOfValueTypes`? The answer may be different depending on whether it's `string | number`, `string | boolean`, `string | number | boolean`, etc.

Comment: That's the thing, it's quite complex. It's coming from a database type definition and it has a lot of nesting, so I want to find an answer that doesn't rely on value type to define the keys. `string` and `number` are part of that type, but it's not limited to just primitive types.

Comment: Well, you'll need to come up with some example which is sufficiently equivalent to your use-case so that the code in your question is a [mcve] - otherwise people won't be able to test their potential answers.

Comment: I did... For sake of this example you can say that I have `type SetOfValueTypes = string | number | boolean;`, but there's no difference what that value is, I need an interface that's identical to `Type1` without redefining it, since that type has a lot of properties in my situation.

Comment: So essentially `[key: string]: SetOfValueTypes` should go away for the third type

Comment: Why not just remove `[key: string]` from Type2 and call it BaseProperties - then create a new Type2 which is `{ [key: string]: SetOfValueTypes; } & BaseProperties` and extend  Type1 from BaseProperties instead? As soon as you extend an interface with a string index you've widened the index to all strings, so you can't do it another way without changing how you've set this up. Could be worth giving more detail on what you're trying to achieve - rather than trying to make this specific setup work

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result with the following type.

```
type KeysOfType1 = keyof {[K in keyof Type1 as string extends K ? never : K]: Type1[K]};
```

Basically, `email` and `phone` are the subsets of `string,` not vice versa. Therefore, checking `string extends "phone"` or `string extends "email"` is not true.